# Maven: verify goal does not open up a browser in Automation Testing

Tags: java, maven, testng

I'm using eclipse to create a run configuration mvn verify and it does not open a browser. I include the maven-failsafe-plugin and maven-compiler-plugin

```
> <plugin>
>      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
>      <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
>      <version>3.0.0-M3</version>
>      <executions>
>           <execution>
>           <goals>
>               <goal>integration-test</goal>
>               <goal>verify</goal>
>            </goals>
>           </execution>
>      </executions>
> </plugin>
```

What wrong with it? I even run mvn install but no browser open up.

Comment: What do you expect in the browser? The summary of the test execution?

Comment: Some action executed according to my coding. I can run it using TestNG-test but this is not what i want because i want to run it on Jenkins.

Comment: No one willing to help me on Maven problem

Comment: You have a TestNG-test and it is not running during mvn test-phase, right? What is the name of the test? Does it corresponds to the default naming pattern? see https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/integration-test-mojo.html at ''includes''

Comment: I had post the maven failsafe plugin configuration at here. Can you pinpoint what is the errors?

Answer (score 2):

A test will automatically be picked up by the maven failsafe-/surefire-plugin if it follows the naming convention, i.e.

> A list of  elements specifying the test filter (by pattern)
>   of tests which should be included in testing. If it is not specified
>   and the test parameter is unspecified as well, the default includes is
>
> ```
> <includes>
>     <include>**/IT*.java</include>
>     <include>**/*IT.java</include>
>     <include>**/*ITCase.java</include>
> </includes>
> ```

see https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/integration-test-mojo.html.

If you can run the test with TestNG from within eclipse then I assume the name of your test is not "correct".

Comment: How to naming the test name correctly according to some naming convention?   @Test(groups= {"Login"}, description="Chrome - Login", priority = 0, dataProvider = "loginCredentials")

Comment: How to specify the include tag also - where is nested to ?

Comment: I tried using include but no browser open up - nested in configuration tag.

Comment: Anyone please help me on this. A billion thanks for your help.

Comment: It is everything said. The name of the class/file must end with one of the mentioned suffixes.

Comment: Can you provide an example?